# Events spanning multiple days are not displayed correctly in fullcalendar

Tags: fullcalendar

My fullcalendar event 'Big Party' starts at monday 10am and ends at wednesday 6am.
So the event should span 3 days in the month view.
The duration is 44 hours (problem because it is less than 48 hours???).

```
title: 'Big Party',
start: '2014-09-15T10:00',
end: '2014-09-17T06:00'
```

The event goes from monday to tuesday in the month view. But why ends the event not at wednesday?

This fiddle shows the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/3E8nk/439/

Thank you
Tobi

Answer (score 11):

You need to change the nextDayThreshold: '09:00:00', // 9am option

See http://jsfiddle.net/3E8nk/440/

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({


    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    defaultDate: '2014-09-15',
    editable: true,
    nextDayThreshold: '00:00:00', // 9am
    events: [
        {
            title: 'Birthday Party',
            start: '2014-09-15T10:00:00',
            end: '2014-09-17T06:00:00'
        }
    ]
});
```